# Which substance has the fastest rate of evaporation at room temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry

> Which substance has the fastest rate of evaporation at room temperature?
>
> **A**) $\ce{CH3OH}$
> **B**) $\ce{C7H16}$
> **C**) $\ce{C6H14}$
> **D**) $\ce{C4H10}$

Comment: Really?!? This is homework. You can't google the boiling points of these?

Comment: @MaxW I'm trying to understand it conceptually. thanks.

Comment: The boiling points would give you a good indication. The vapor pressure at room temperature would be exact. **B**,  **C**, and **D** have a isomers. Truthfully figuring out the isomers and looking up the data will help you learn something about chemistry that us just giving you the answer won't teach you.

Comment: The rate of evaporation depends not only on the equilibrium vapor pressure but also on the diffusion coefficient of the species in air (assuming that the temperature is somehow held constant).

Comment: Why don't you just look up the vapor pressures and diffusion coefficients (in air) of these substances at room temperature and do a mass transfer analysis to estimate the rate of evaporation of each?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I started a table for you. I think all these chemicals would be in Wikipedia. Not sure if all the data is there, but I'd guess so. As I said the three alkanes have multiple isomers, so you need to copy lines in the table.

\begin{array}{cccc}
\hline
\text{Formula} & \text{Name} & \text{Boiling point} & \text{Vap. press.} \\
&&&(\pu{kPa @ 20 ^\circ C}) \\
\hline
\ce{CH3OH} & \text{Methanol} & 64.7 & 13.02 \\ 
\ce{C7H16} & & & \\
\ce{C6H14} & & & \\
\ce{C4H10} & & & \\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Let's start with easy one. How many isomers does $\ce{C4H10}$ have? What are the names?

Comment: A) CH3OH has hydrogen bonds therefore is much stronger than the dispersion forces in the other molecules, so wouldn't it have the slowest rate of evaporation?

Comment: $\ce{CH3OH}$ is so different than the other molecules that such comparison is pretty useless. For isomers I can take an educated guess at to which isomer will have greatest and lowest volatility. // I just know the answer because I've handle a lot of these chemicals. But If I just tell you then you won't learn anything. If you go to the trouble of figuring this out you will really learn something. // *Again* - How many isomers does C4H10 have? What are the names?